# Regex Generation Assistance

Tags: regex

I need some hopefully easy and quick help. I am getting a string of data from a barcode and I need to splice it to obtain three different values - Account Number, Date, and Invoice Number.

The regex has to be written for .Net Framework.

An example of what the barcode will return looks like this –

```
000295934009000306511302017001
```

The first 9 digits is the Account Number. I’ve got that figured out by using this - `^\d{9}`

The next 10 digits is the Invoice Number. I am not sure what regex expression would give me that.

Then, the 8 digits following the Invoice Number is the date (in this example it is `11302017`). I need to pull that and put it into a `MM/DD/YYYY` format.

I will be creating a named group pattern for this too.

```
(?<account>^\d{9})(?<date>XXXXXXX)(?<invoice>XXXXXXX) - the X's are what I need to figure out.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: what have you tried and what issues are you facing?

Comment: What do you do with the 001 at the end then?

Comment: For the trailing 001 it's a (\d{3}) or to ignore everything else regardless of length .*

Answer (score 0):

This is the regex:

```
(\d{9})(\d{10})(\d{8})
```

Self explanatory: group 1 9 digits, group 2 10 digits and group 3 8 digits.

You can use it like this:

```
string pattern = @"(\d{9})(\d{10})(\d{8})";
string input = @"000295934009000306511302017001";
var match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
var accountNumber = match.Groups[1].Value;
var invoiceNumber = match.Groups[2].Value;
var date = match.Groups[3].Value;
```

To get the `DateTime` object, use `ParseExact`:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(date, "MMddyyyy",  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Remember to add using directives for `System.Text.RegularExpressions` and `System.Globalization`!

Answer (score 0):

This is the regex:

```
(\d{9})(\d{10})([0-1][0-2][0-3][0-9]\d{4})
```

accountNumber - Group1

invoiceNumber - Group2

date - Groups3